# Schengen visa - Duration of Days

Tags: schengen-visas

My Schengen visa is valid from 22nd May to 16th April 2018.
Duration of Stay is 11 Days.

This is my current itinerary -
Leave from Bangalore to Germany  - on 22nd March (Reaching Germany on 22nd March)
Leave from Germany to Bangalore - on 2nd April (Leaving Germany at 9:45am)

I want to confirm whether this itinerary is fine under 11 days or is it 12 days (if I include both the entry and exit dates)

I am confused on this. The embassy told they will get back but haven't responded yet.

Also, it is better to apply for a new visa or change the tickets (changing tickets is much more expensive)

Please let me know.

Comment: I assume your visa is from 22nd of March 2018 to 16th of April 2018, if so, can you edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Both the entry and exit days are included in the duration of your stay since you are legally in the Schengen zone on 22 March and 2 April both. It doesn't matter whether your spend the whole day, or just five minutes, it will still count as a whole day.

Comment: in that case, should i apply for a new visa (i am worried that it may take more time) or change my tickets ( much more expensive option). What do you suggest

Comment: While changing flights will be a sure shot way of overcoming this problem, it certainly will be more expensive. You can also try searching for one way return flights to India, which may turn out to be cheaper than trying to change flights.

Comment: can i ask for changing my visa by applying again with the fees and documents. As per the rules, i think i can but i am not sure if this will invite extra scrutiny to my application.

Comment: by changing i mean cancelling the existing one and issuing a new one.

Comment: You can apply for another Schengen visa, but as I understand it will only be issued for dates after your first visa ends. Which would technically make it valid for you to leave, but I'm not too sure about how this will work.

Answer (score 0):

YES, it's 12 days, since departure day counts as well.

I suppose you are flying to and from Frankfurt-Main (FRA), given that you mention Bangalore. Transit area is open 24 hours at FRA, and so are some shops there. Contact your airline to find out if it is possible to check in the day before. If yes, just clear your passport check before the midnight, so you 'exit' on 1st April, that's it. Keep in mind that most German airports will have security and border checkpoints closed during the night curfew (2300-0500 hrs), and you must find out yourself how early do you need to come there.

Alternatively, if spending the night at the airport is not your thing, you might change the itinerary to multi-city to fly out for a cheaper price from somewhere else, and to catch a low-cost flight there. Remember, Schengen Area is not just Germany. There is plenty of cities to find a cheaper ticket from.